# How get URL from a file in jar

Tags: java, jar, classloader, executable-jar, getresource

I need to get the file in my project put a value ( like hello word). But I need to create a jar after:

```
home 
   grafica
      indice_corrente.txt
      finestraprincipale.java
```

so I access to this file (indice_corrente.txt) in this way:

```
FinestraPrincipale.class.getClassLoader().getResource("src/grafica/indice_corrente.txt").toString();
```

I need to get the url so I can open this file with PritWriter in the jar and write into

This code give me nullpointer exception. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `txt` file under `src/resources` and then use path relative to `resources`. Like so:

```
FinestraPrincipale.class.getClassLoader()
    .getResource("/indice_corrente.txt")
    .toString();
```

Comment: @ddd well then, it shouldn't be there :)